# Probability of a birthday in each and every month in a group of 25

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

I know the answer to this question for a group of 12, namely $\frac{12!}{12^{12}}$, but how much does it increase as extras are added to the group? Specifically up to a group size of $25$.

Comment: Are you assuming (unrealistically) that a randomly selected birthday is equally likely to fall in any of the $12$ months?

Comment: This becomes the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector's_problem).

Answer (score 2):

There are [$\left\{\begin{smallmatrix}n\\k\end{smallmatrix}\right\}$ many different ways to partition a set of $n$ elements into $k$ nonempty subsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind), (*the unsigned stirling number of the second kind*), and $k!$ many ways to label those subsets using a number $1,2,\dots,k$.

Using $n$ as the number of people, and $k=12$ for the months of the year, assuming each month is equally likely to occur this would imply the probability that all twelve months appear within $n$ people to be:

$$Pr(X_n)=\dfrac{12!\left\{\begin{smallmatrix}n\\12\end{smallmatrix}\right\}}{12^n}$$

Alternatively written:

[$$Pr(X_n)=\frac{\sum\limits_{j=0}^{12}(-1)^j\binom{12}{j}j^n}{12^n}$$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Bsum+j%3D0+to+12+(-1)%5Ej(12+choose+j)j%5En%5D%2F12%5En)

Replace $n$ in the above link with a specific value to calculate the result.

The probability for $12$ people would be approximately $0.0000537$, the same as you calculated earlier

The probability for $15$ people would be approximately $0.00331013$

The probability for $20$ people would be approximately $0.0513537$

The probability for $25$ people would be approximately $0.181899$

The probability for $50$ people would be approximately $0.852335$

The probability for $100$ people would be approximately $0.998004$